# How to proxy forward ttyd using Apache

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, portforwarding, tty

`ttyd` is a good web based terminal:
https://github.com/tsl0922/ttyd

By default, it will use port 7681, so after successfully configured, I can access terminal from `localhost:7681` in browser.

We have web server powered by Apache on port 80, and only this port is open to Internet. So in order to access ttyd, I'd like to set a proxy forwarding `localhost/shell` to `localhost:7681`, and I set it in `httpd.conf` like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPass /shell http://127.0.0.1:7681/
    ProxyPassReverse /shell http://127.0.0.1:7681/
</VirtualHost>
```

When I visit `localhost/shell`, it showed me the ttyd page with "Connection closed" message. It seems the connection is not hold. How to solve this problem?

Comment: I tried with Gotty https://github.com/yudai/gotty , the same problem exists.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you need to proxy *two* protocols, namely `http` and `ws` (WebSocket). Without specific handling for the latter, Apache will (of course) use the former for everything which does not work.

You can observe this behaviour (use of different protocols) if you look at the `ttyd` log and open `http://127.0.0.1:7681/` in the browser. Conversely, with the original two `Proxy*` directives in place, opening the browser's web console and accessing `http://127.0.0.1/shell/` shows that all requests to "`[/]ws`" fail while `ttyd` will only log `http` requests for everything (including "`[/]ws`").

The following solves this (note that this requires `mod_proxy_wstunnel` and `mod_rewrite`):

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} upgrade [NC]
    RewriteRule /shell/?(.*) "ws://127.0.0.1:7681/$1" [P,L]
    ProxyPass /shell/ http://127.0.0.1:7681/
    ProxyPassReverse /shell/ http://127.0.0.1:7681/
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache with wstunnel extension enabled, in proxy setting:

```
ProxyPass /webash/ws ws://127.0.0.1:7681/ws
ProxyPass /webash http://127.0.0.1:7681/
ProxyPassReverse /webash http://127.0.0.1:7681/
```

Tested in Ubuntu 14.04, startup with security credential:

```
./ttyd_linux.x86_64 -c Somebody:SuperPassword bash > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```